# net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException - Counterparty flow on C=GB,L=London,O=NodeA had an internal error and has terminated

Tags: corda

I am using release-v1 of Corda.

My app has three nodes - A, B and C. Following are the flows defined in the app -

Flow 1: A sends a trade request to B and C

Flow 2: B approves the trade request, self-signs it, gets signature from A and closes the trade.

Flow 1 works fine. While executing workflow 2, I get net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException error.

The logs of node A shows following lines,

```
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Counterparty flow on C=GB,L=London,O=NodeA had an internal error and has terminated
    at       net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.erroredEnd(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:446)
    at     net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.confirmReceiveType(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:429)
```

I referred to WorkflowTransactionBuildTutorial.kt for the flows -
(https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V1/docs/source/example-code/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/docs/WorkflowTransactionBuildTutorial.kt)

**1. I am executing following code for workflow 1**

```
val tradeProposal = IOUContract.State(OU( IouId, IouCurrency, IouAmount), serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), nodeB, nodeC).contract.IOUContract"

val IOU_CONTRACT_ID = "net.corda.bgc.contract.IOUContract"

val tx = TransactionBuilder(notary).withItems(
              StateAndContract(tradeProposal, IOU_CONTRACT_ID),                     
Command(IOUContract.Commands.Issue(),listOf(tradeProposal.sender.owningKey)))
              .addAttachment(secHash)

tx.setTimeWindow(serviceHub.clock.instant(), 180.seconds)

val signedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(tx)
subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx, setOf(serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first(), nodeB, nodeC)))

return signedTx.tx.outRef<IOUContract.State>(0)
```

**This code works fine. Both nodes B and C receive the IOU request from nodeA with status as "NEW".**

**2. I am executing following code for workflow 2**

Code for sending the signed transaction to the originator and await
their signature to confirm

```
val tx = TransactionBuilder(notary).
            withItems(
                  latestRecord,
                  StateAndContract(newState, IOU_CONTRACT_ID),
                  Command(IOUContract.Commands.Completed(),                              listOf(serviceHub.myInfo.legalIdentities.first().owningKey, latestRecord.state.data.nodeA.owningKey)))

tx.setTimeWindow(serviceHub.clock.instant(), 600.seconds)

val selfSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(tx)

val session = initiateFlow(newState.nodeA)

val allPartySignedTx = session.sendAndReceive<TransactionSignature>(selfSignedTx).unwrap {
val agreedTx = selfSignedTx + it
agreedTx.verifySignaturesExcept(notary.owningKey)
agreedTx.tx.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub).verify()
agreedTx
}

subFlow(FinalityFlow(allPartySignedTx, setOf(newState.nodeA, newState.nodeB, newState.nodeC)))

return allPartySignedTx.tx.outRef(0)
```

Flow to receive the final decision on a proposal

```
val completeTx = receive<SignedTransaction>(source).unwrap {
it.verifySignaturesExcept(ourIdentity.owningKey, it.tx.notary!!.owningKey)
val ltx = it.toLedgerTransaction(serviceHub, false)
ltx.verify()
val state = ltx.outRef<IOUContract.State>(0)
}
it

val ourSignature = serviceHub.createSignature(completeTx)
send(ourSignature)
```

However, the above code fails and the error net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException is thrown.

**Please, can any one guide me to correct the above code
OR redirect me to an example that matches the required workflows?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.

Replaced the "sendandreceive" function with the "collectsignaturesflow" function, in the approval flow. Now both initiator and approval flows are working.

Referred the link - 
https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an exception of the form:

```
net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: 
    Counterparty flow on C=GB,L=London,O=NodeA had an internal error and has terminated
```

This means that the counterparty node (`NodeA` in this case) has encountered an exception. You should check the counterparty node's logs. Each node has logs in a `/logs` folder.